# How do I call up a function from anywhere in the program in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
while (inDungeonRoom1 == true) {

    if (choice == "torch" || choice == "Torch" || choice == "pick up torch" ||
      choice == "Pick up torch" || choice == "grab torch" ||
       choice == "Grab torch") {

          torch++;
```

I want to be able to call a function, like information about where you are anywhere within the program, without messing with if statements.

Comment: What do you want?? Please properly explain it

Comment: I don't see any function declaration, definition or call in your code. Declarations and definitions are your best friends here, I guess, and they are also the fundamental parts of the language, so you'll have to learn them well any way.

Comment: Unrelated editorial aside: Never ever write `if (` *whatever* `== true)` .  Just write `if (` *whatever* `)`

Comment: @Zack: What's so terrible about if ( whatever == true)? Seems like a minor style issue to me.

Comment: If *whatever* returns a value which is nonzero but not equal to 1, the test will fail when it shouldn't have.

Comment: I dont understand how people have gave answer to that question.(easily as anyone see ,  It will give so many compiler error due to absence of "}". )

Comment: @Emile: A different answer than Zack's: If whatever is a bool, and you compare it against true, you get another bool. Why not compare that against true as well? if (((whatever == true) == true) == true) etc. ?? How do we know when to stop?

Comment: @Zack: Ahh... Thanks! That never occured to me. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be programming an [interactive fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_fiction) game.  You want a more structured way of interpreting player input -- in other words, a parser.  Natural language parsing is obscenely difficult, but there are some good-enough-for-this-job parsers that you could reuse.  I recommend you look through the [IFwiki](http://www.ifwiki.org/)'s [guide to authoring systems](http://www.ifwiki.org/index.php/Category%3aAuthoring_system).

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your function as `static` (if a member function), or as quasiverse mentioned simply declare it above where you want to use it. Then, you can simply call it as needed.

Also important is that comparing strings using `==` is really not a good idea. If you're using C-strings, you'll want to look into using [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/), or if you're using C++ strings it's worth looking at [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

**EDIT:** updated wording a little in response to Sergey's comment.

Comment: @Sergey: you can, but it's really just syntactic sugar for `compare` anyway. If using `strings` it's more of a style thing than anything else, I guess. `Compare` also has the advantage of being more flexible than `==`, though.

Comment: first time I ever see someone recommand not to use `operator==` for basic string comparison. By any chance, are you used to code in Java ?

Comment: @ereOn: for me, it is more of a stylistic thing than anything else. I have been using C++ more than anything else for a while, but you're right - I did start out in Java a while back. Could well be that...